# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 3

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am pulling data from internet but I can only display 1 piece of data on the screen and I get the has Size problem How can I solve these two errors?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<PostModel>?>(
      future: _postService.fetchPostsItems(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final result = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: result.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              return CustomComponents(
                title: result[index].authorName ?? '',
                subTitle: result[index].createdAt ?? '',
                profileImageUrl: result[index].authorProfileImage ?? '',
                postImageUrl: result[index].media ?? '',
                description: result[index].description ?? '',
                likeCount: result[index].likeCount ?? 0,
                dislikeCount: result[index].disLikeCount ?? 0,
                commentCount: result[index].comments?.length ?? 0,
                commentTitle: result[index].comments?[index].authorName ?? '',
                commentDescription: result[index].description ?? '',
                commentImageUrl: result[index].authorProfileImage ?? '',
              );
            }),
          );
        }
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result[index].comments?[index].
```

This may cause a problem. Your ListView is as long as result, but that doesn't mean that your comments in result are as long as the result length.